# python string differences

Tags: python

I am seeing that a string comparison of two identical strings ('fraiser') in Python is failing. When using `repr(str1)` and `repr(str2)` I get different results, but I don't know how to interpret them or why they return different things. Any help?

```
>>> repr(list(lowerAndMakeSet(fileChunks))[3])

"'frasier'"


>>> repr(list(lowerAndMakeSet(c))[2])

"['f', 'r', 'a', 'i', 's', 'e', 'r']"
```

Comment: A few questions come to mind: 1. What are you trying to accomplish? 2. What version of python are you using? 3. What does the lowerAndMakeSet function do (please post the code). 4. What is fileChunks (please post code)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your second "string" that you are `repr`ing is actually a list and not a string. You can see this if you do `type(list(lowerAndMakeSet(c))[2])`.